# Continually adding length to an element on keydown

Tags: javascript, html, css, keyboard-events

```js
function Parse(css) {
  var a = "";
  for (var i in css)
    if (!isNaN(parseInt(css[i]))) a += css[i];
    else break;
  return parseInt(a)
}

function Player() {
  return document.getElementById('PLAYER');
}
var P = {
  HEIGHT: Parse(window.getComputedStyle(Player(), null).getPropertyValue('height')),
  WIDTH: Parse(window.getComputedStyle(Player(), null).getPropertyValue('width')),
  TOP: Parse(window.getComputedStyle(Player(), null).getPropertyValue('top')),
  LEFT: Parse(window.getComputedStyle(Player(), null).getPropertyValue('left'))
};
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(k) {
  switch (k.key.toLowerCase()) {
    case 'arrowleft':
      Object.assign(Player().style, {
        left: `${P.LEFT - P.WIDTH}px`
      });
      break;
    case 'arrowright':
      Object.assign(Player().style, {
        left: `${P.LEFT + P.WIDTH}px`
      });
      break;
    case 'arrowup':
      Object.assign(Player().style, {
        top: `${P.TOP - P.HEIGHT}px`
      });
      break;
    case 'arrowdown':
      Object.assign(Player().style, {
        top: `${P.TOP + P.HEIGHT}px`
      });
      break;
  }
}, true);
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#PLAYER {
  position: relative;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="PLAYER"></div>
```

I've been trying to make a very basic test for a possible game in Javascript, but I'm running into some bugs that are hard to understand.

The issue is my black div square element (resting snugly at 0,0) only moves in a square, aside from moving continually in one direction by adding its own width or height to its left or top according to which arrow key is pressed.

It's honestly bewildering.

Any and all input and/or advice is greatly appreciated. I'm quite new to the scene of making games at all.

Comment: What is issue? Can you create a stacksnippets to demonstrate?

Comment: just added one.

Answer (score 0):

Set `position` of element to `relative`

```js
function Parse(css) {
  var a = "";
  for (var i in css)
    if (!isNaN(parseInt(css[i]))) a += css[i];
    else break;
  return parseInt(a)
}

function Player() {
  return document.getElementById('PLAYER');
}

window.onload = function() {
  var P = {
    HEIGHT: Parse(window.getComputedStyle(Player(), null).getPropertyValue('height')),
    WIDTH: Parse(window.getComputedStyle(Player(), null).getPropertyValue('width')),
    TOP: Parse(window.getComputedStyle(Player(), null).getPropertyValue('top')),
    LEFT: Parse(window.getComputedStyle(Player(), null).getPropertyValue('left'))
  };
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(k) {
  switch (k.key.toLowerCase()) {
    case 'arrowleft':
      Object.assign(Player().style, {
        left: `${P.LEFT - P.WIDTH}px`
      });
      break;
    case 'arrowright':
      Object.assign(Player().style, {
        left: `${P.LEFT + P.WIDTH}px`
      });
      break;
    case 'arrowup':
      Object.assign(Player().style, {
        top: `${P.TOP - P.HEIGHT}px`
      });
      break;
    case 'arrowdown':
      Object.assign(Player().style, {
        top: `${P.TOP + P.HEIGHT}px`
      });
      break;
  }
}, true);

}
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#PLAYER {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: #000;
  position: relative;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="PLAYER"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for reminding me to add that, but it doesn't remove the bug.

Comment: @Scrow What is the "bug"? Do you mean the element not being visible after N clicks? You do not set `width` at `javascript` at Question, `top` and `left` are set.